# How can pull a value from multiple object mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a document and few collections like this

```
_id:objectId()
user:objectId()
notification:[
   0:{
     time:2021-08-02T02:46:37.816+00:00
     read:false
     status: added
     }
   1:{
     time:2021-08-02T02:46:37.816+00:00
     read:false
     status: added
     }
]
```

I want to update `read:false` to `read:true`.

Currently I am using this query:

```
     db
    .get()
    .collection(collection.NOTIFICATION_COLLECTION)
    .update(
      { user: objectId(id), "notification.read": false },
      { $set: { "notification.$.read": true } },
      { multi: true }
    );
```

Result after running this query:

```
notification:[
   0:{
     time:2021-08-02T02:46:37.816+00:00
     read:true
     status: added
     }
   1:{
     time:2021-08-02T02:46:37.816+00:00
     read:false
     status: added
     }
]
```

First value is changed, I need to update all values to `read : true` - how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this;

```
"notification.$[].read": true
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/embedded-arrays/#match-all-array-elements